# Reset password subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, change-password

I come to you today to ask some advise about a coding in which I still have issues. It was working at the beginning as it was in a normal form, but then I decided to adapt it to the real situation where it would actually to base its analytics on subform elements.

Would you mind taking a look at it and tell what is wrong ?

thanks a lot for your help:

```
 Public Function Resetpassword()
'On Error GoTo Macro1_Err
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm


        If DLookup("[User login]![Password]", "[User login]", "[User login]![Username]= [Textlogin]") = frm.Forms.navigationsubform.Textpass.Value Then
            If frm.Forms.navigationsubform.Textnewpass.Value = frm.Forms.navigationsubform.Textnewpassconfirmation.Value Then

            strsql = "UPDATE [User login]" _
            & "SET [User login].[Password] =" & frm.Forms.navigationsubform.[Textnewpass].Value _
            & "WHERE ((([User login].[Username])=" & frm.Forms.navigationsubform.[Textlogin].Value & "));"


            DoCmd.RunSQL strsql


            Beep
                MsgBox "Your password has been effective. Thanks!", vbOKOnly, "Success"
            Exit Function
            Else
                Beep
                MsgBox "You must confirm you new password.", vbOKOnly, ""
            End If
        Else
            Beep
            MsgBox "You might have enter an invalid password, please retry.", vbOKOnly, ""
        End If



'Macro1_Exit:
    'Exit Function

'Macro1_Err:
    'MsgBox Error$
    'Resume Macro1_Exit

End Function
```

I am getting the 2465 error : 'Application defined or object defined error"

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the answer. I am posting it here in case some others are meetings the same issue.

My code was not working because it did not take into account the fact that he was in a subform.

Final working code:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Reset Password
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function Resetpassword()
'On Error GoTo Macro1_Err
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm


        If DLookup("[Password]", "[User login]", "[Username]='" & frm.navigationsubform.Form![Textlogin].Value & "'") = frm.navigationsubform.Form!Textpass.Value Then
            If frm.navigationsubform.Form!Textnewpass.Value = frm.navigationsubform.Form!Textnewpassconfirmation.Value Then

             strsql = "UPDATE [User login]" _
            & "SET [User login].[Password] ='" & frm.navigationsubform.Form![Textnewpass] _
            & "' WHERE ((([User login].[Username])='" & frm.navigationsubform.Form![Textlogin] & "'));"


            DoCmd.RunSQL strsql


            Beep
                MsgBox "Your password has been effective. Thanks!", vbOKOnly, "Success"
            Exit Function
            Else
                Beep
                MsgBox "You must confirm you new password.", vbOKOnly, ""
            End If
        Else
            Beep
            MsgBox "You might have enter an invalid password, please retry.", vbOKOnly, ""
        End If



'Macro1_Exit:
    'Exit Function

'Macro1_Err:
    'MsgBox Error$
    'Resume Macro1_Exit

End Function
```

Regards,